# Авторизация в вконтакте

Tags: python, auth, вконтакте, python-3.x

подскажите пожалуйста как авторизоваться в вконтакте через скрипт?

я умею через скрипт авторизовываться на обычных форумах типа IPB. но в случае с вконтакте вижу через firebug что передаётся очень большое количество кук. неужели они все нужны?

и с набором для строки запроса пожалуйста тоже подскажите. какие данные необходимы.

если интересно, для авторизации на форумах у меня используется примерно такой код:

```
import pprint
import requests
import bs4
url = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text)
loginForm = soup.find('form', {'id': 'login'})
hiddenAuthKey = soup.find('input', {'name': 'auth_key'})['value']
authData = {    
            'ips_username': 'йцукен',
            'ips_password': 'йцукен',
            'auth_key': hiddenAuthKey,
            'rememberMe': 1,
            'referer':  'http://forum.saransk.ru/'
}
pprint.pprint(authData)
cookies = dict(invbf_session_id='2412121525sdg')
pprint.pprint(cookies)
req = requests.get(url, params=authData, cookies=cookies)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text)
signLinkNotLogged = soup.find('a', {'id': 'sign_in'})
if signLinkNotLogged:
    print('not_enter')
else:
    print('enter')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я писал скрипт для авторизации во VK, правда для python 2. Он выложен на [GitHub](https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth). Там есть два файла [`vk_auth.py`](https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth/blob/master/vk_auth.py) - собственно модуль для авторизации и [`fetch_photos.py`](https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth/blob/master/fetch_photos.py) - пример использования. Для обработки кук использовал `urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor`. В python3 он тоже есть, но кажется переехал в `urllib.request`.

**UPD**: на [Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143972/) есть полное описание того, как скрипт устроен.